# Linux search tool with results selection and copy functionality

Tags: linux, file, ubuntu, search

I am using Ubuntu now but am used to Windows where i can natively search for specific files inside a folder, select all the found entries and directly select and copy all of them in order to paste to another folder.
Now I found that this is not possible with Ubuntu. I digged on the internets a bit and found several search tools like catfish, gnome-search-tool or recoll... but all they do is search, no selection or copying of the found files.
Therefore, I'd like to ask you guys if you have any idea on how to get this functionality? 
Why I am asking here - because the Ubuntu forum is either dead or nobody has an idea.

Comment: come on guys, is there really no solution close to the one in windows?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you want to select txt files in `sourcedir` and move them to `targetdir`.

```
cd sourcedir  
find . -name "*.txt" -level 0 -exec mv "{}" targetdir "{}" ";"
```

The exact syntax for your flavor of linux may vary slightly - in particular the `-level 0` might use a different keyword and the `"{}" ";"` at the end might be different.

Comment: yeah i could do so, but, as i am used to windows, i'd like to do it via a gui - just need to know if there is a tool that will do that.